# How correctly generate html select option with php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

yesterday, I was designing a platform to enter products and their quantities using drop-down lists, but I had to generate them using a button, so I had to use javascript. It worked, but at the moment of sending the data by post only takes the last Select generated, then the code and the result.

```
    <form id="pedido" name="pedido" action="funciones/pedido.php" method="post" >

<table name="pedidos" class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
                                 <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Producto</th>
                                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

</table>
<br>


</form>
<center>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"  onclick="myCreateFunction()">Agregar Producto</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Eliminar Producto</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  form="pedido" type="submit">Guardar</button></center>
<br>
```

and the Javascript

```
<script>
function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);

    <? $sql="select * from productodist where  rut_dist='".$_GET['id']."';";
$resultado=mysql_query($sql);
$x=0;?>
    var element = document.createElement("select");
 <? while($datos=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
     $x++?>
    var option<? echo $x; ?> = document.createElement("option");
    option<? echo $x; ?> .innerHTML = "<? echo  $datos['Descripcion'] ?>";
    option<? echo $x; ?>.value = "<? echo  $datos['CodArticulo'] ?>";
    element.add(option<? echo $x; ?>, null);
    element.name = "producto<? echo $x; ?>";


    <?
 }
    ?>
    cell.appendChild(element);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("select");
    //element2.type = "select"

    <?  for ($y=1;$y<=100;$y++){
        ?>    var option<? echo $y; ?> = document.createElement("option");
    option<? echo $y; ?>.innerHTML = "<? echo $y; ?>";
    option<? echo $y; ?>.value = "<? echo $y; ?>";
    element2.add(option<? echo $y; ?>, null);
    element2.name = "cantidad<? echo $x; ?>";
    <?  }?>
    cell2.appendChild(element2);
}

function myDeleteFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(1);
}
</script>
```

And then when I send it, the post array anwer me this.

```
Array ( [producto30] => 20008 [cantidad30] => 1 )
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks you in advance!

Comment: This is how it looks  http://puu.sh/v3mPv/991866d901.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set attribute of option is selected, so form can read what value have to send. if you want to send more that one value , you have to set attribute select to multiple, and mark option value that you want to send value as selected.

/* mark your option to selected*/

```
option.setAttribute('selected', true);
```

/*add attr multiple to make select can be select more than one value.*/

```
element2.setAttribute(multiple, "multiple");
```

i hope this help.

the name of your select is same, so form will replace all and get the last select. 
you can see in here
[name of select same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m99U.png)

so, you need to add class in select to make it simple to count.

```
/*we add attr class*/
element.setAttribute(class, "element");
element2.setAttribute(class, "element2");

/*here we count created select*/
    var x = $(".element").length;
```

because element 1 and 2 is same length we don't need to count element 2
and just set the name of element like.

```
  element.name = "producto"+x;
  element2.name = "cantidad"+x;
```

this the final function.

```
function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    var x = parseFloat($(".element").length); /*this  for count length of class element*/

    <? $sql="select * from productodist where  rut_dist='".$_GET['id']."';";
        $resultado=mysql_query($sql);
        $x=0;
    ?>
    var element = document.createElement("select");
    element.setAttribute("Class","element"); /*this will be add class element into input select1 */
    <? 
        while($datos=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $x++;
     ?>

        var option<? echo $x; ?>        = document.createElement("option");
        option<? echo $x; ?> .innerHTML = "<? echo  $datos['Descripcion'] ?>";
        option<? echo $x; ?>.value      = "<? echo  $datos['CodArticulo'] ?>";
        element.add(option<? echo $x; ?>, null);
    <?
        }
    ?>

    element.name                    = "producto"+(x+1); /*i move outside looping so it's just set once and set name element +length of select has been create + 1*/
    cell.appendChild(element);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("select");
    element2.setAttribute("Class","element"); /*this will be add class element into input select2 */
    //element2.type = "select"

    <?  
    for ($y=1;$y<=100;$y++){
    ?>    
        var option<? echo $y; ?>       = document.createElement("option");
        option<? echo $y; ?>.innerHTML = "<? echo $y; ?>";
        option<? echo $y; ?>.value     = "<? echo $y; ?>";
        element2.add(option<? echo $y; ?>, null);

    <?  
    }
    ?>

    element2.name                  = "cantidad"+(x+1);
    element.name                    = "producto"+(x+1); /*i move outside looping so it's just set once and set name element2 + length of select has been create + 1*/
    cell2.appendChild(element2);
}
```

let me know it's working or not.

Comment: I have multiple select tags more then one select with multiple selection, like this http://puu.sh/v3mPv/991866d901.png :)

Comment: did you check inspect element about your select name? are the select name is increase? or just use same name? because on your code i don't see you count select has been create. or for a dynamic just set select name as array. like  element.name = "producto[]" same for element2.name = "cantidad[]";

Comment: Yes, I put a count in the beggining of the while cycle, btw this is the result of the inspector. https://pastebin.com/gR52rvfV :)

Comment: i just edit my answer, just check it, you count row of option value from database, not how much select element has been created.

Comment: I can not fit your suggestion into my code, I have no idea where it goes, Excuse me :(

Comment: Well it take me a while, but i fix it, and now i get some differents values. Check it: `Array ( [producto1] => 40031 [cantidad4] => 1 [cantidad3] => 2 [cantidad2] => 3 [cantidad1] => 4 [cantidad0] => 5 )`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you generate HTML select option with PHP.

Put this at the top of your php script.

```
<?php
$sql="select * from productodist where  rut_dist='".$_GET['id']."';";
$resultado=mysql_query($sql);
$datos=mysql_fetch_array($resultado);

$selectProducts = '';
$selectProducts .= '<select name="producto">'; // maybe add multiple attribute if you need multiple values sent
foreach($datos as $dato) {
    $selectProducts .= '<option value="'.$dato['CodArticulo'].'">'.$dato['Descripcion'].'</option>';
}
$selectProducts .= '</select>';
?>
```

Then anywhere in your HTML you can display the select:

```
<?php echo $selectProducts; ?>
```

Remove that PHP mixup in your Javascript. It is really not the way to do this...

Note: Using `<?` instead of `<?php` is deprecated and can lead to errors that make your app fail to run on newer PHP versions.

Comment: Thanks,  it's very helpfull, I'll try it in this way, but just for context, I want something like this http://puu.sh/v3mPv/991866d901.png :)